# Object is set to nil automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, null

first here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.elements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", nil];
    self.elements2 = @"Lorem ipsum";
    NSLog(@"%@", self.elements);

    [self loadContent];
}
```

He prints, that _elements is correctly initialized also after `loadContent`, _elements contains three objects.
But only a few lines later in the method `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`:, which is called directly after the `viewDidLoad` method, _elements is `nil`.
I don't know why my app is settings _elements to `nil`?

Thanks iComputerfreak

---

### Edit

I uploaded my full code to gist.github:
https://gist.github.com/iComputerfreak/fa3d3ee925c45cd6e1f2

---

### Console Output

Okay here my console output:

```
// in viewDidLoad (after setting): 
2014-05-13 16:56:14.292 HFG Vertretungsplan[1051:60b] (
    "Object 1",
    "Object 2",
    "Object 3"
)
// numberOfComponents called automatically:
2014-05-13 16:56:14.298 HFG Vertretungsplan[1051:60b] numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (null)
2014-05-13 16:56:14.303 HFG Vertretungsplan[1051:60b] numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (null)
// viewWillAppear method reached:
2014-05-13 16:56:14.306 HFG Vertretungsplan[1051:60b] View will appear
2014-05-13 16:56:14.306 HFG Vertretungsplan[1051:60b] Elements in viewWillAppear: ( // NSLog("%@", self.elements);
    "Object 1",
    "Object 2",
    "Object 3"
)
// [self.elementsPicker reloadAllComponents];
2014-05-13 16:56:14.307 HFG Vertretungsplan[1051:60b] numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (null)
2014-05-13 16:56:14.308 HFG Vertretungsplan[1051:60b] Elements after reloadAllComponents: (
    "Object 1",
    "Object 2",
    "Object 3"
)
```

So only while reloading the components is elements nil. Before and after that, it has content.

Comment: How is _elements defined?  Is it the iVar behind a property? If so, you should use self.elements, not _elements and you should ensure the property is (strong)

Comment: I use Automatic Reference Counting. So [_elements retain] is not possible.

Comment: Have you defined `_elements` separately or is it inferred from the `@property`? i.e. do you have a line somewhere like... `NSMutableArray *_elements ...`

Comment: I feel like there is code missing from this. Could you show all the code involved here. Like the whole class or something. Use gist.github.com to upload a large amount of code and then link it here.

Comment: @Fogmeister: In the .m file is not much more code. I paste the header file in my answer...

Comment: Do you by chance redefine it somewhere else? Could you please post more code of what happens next?

Comment: @user1264176: There is not much code. Only the viewDidLoad and the loadContent method. In the loadContent method, he reads a username and a password of the NSUserDefaults and decrypts the password. Then I only have the UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource methods implemented. There is not more code.

Comment: This tutorial looks very nice: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn%5Fobjectivec/
But it is from 2008...

Comment: BTW, try to clean your project and restart Xcode. Sometimes it caches strange things :)

Comment: Project cleaned, Xcode restarted, nothing happened :D

Comment: Ok, I have made a new project with your files. Works fine for me. I have cleaned up HUDs and Jsomething since I don't have that.

Comment: Okay I delete the file now and recreate it. Maybe this works.

Comment: Recreated files. Still the same thing.

Comment: Try this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57813900/test_stack.zip. This works for me. This is what I have copied from your gist and put into new project.

Comment: This works for me too
This is my project: dl.jonasfrey.de/project.zip

Comment: Ok, I have found the problem but I don't know yet what causes it. The problem is that there are 2 SettingsViewController instances in your project. See detailed answer in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually make headers like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *userTextField;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPickerView *elementPicker; // I would suggest to use sttong for outlets if you are planning to move them out of their superview
//@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *elements; // if you use ARC I would suggest to forget about retain in favor of strong.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *elements;
//@property NSString *elements2; // I would suggest not to rely on implicit property specifier declarations in favor of more verbosity
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *elements2;


- (IBAction)userOrPasswordChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then in .h or .m file you don't need to declare `_elements` (or `elements`) one more time since it is automatically created with property declaration. If you need to declare it (it is needed in some cases) you should be careful and read about naming convention.

With such header the original questions problem should be solved unless you do something extravagant in your remaining code.

EDIT: I have dug a bit in topic starter's real code. The problem is that he has 2 instances of SettingsViewController. They are both set in his storyboard. [image: screenshot of storyboard]

so one of the instances is used to be presented to screen and thus `viewDidLoad` method is called and `_elements` is populated and another is created silently by storyboard and used as the instance used as datasource and delegate of UIPickerView. The second instance is not shown so its `viewDidLoad` method is not called and `_elements` are nil.

So if you print `self` along with `elements` you will see the difference.

If you remove the second instance in the picture you will get everything working.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So @synthesize is not required in the .m file?
Because I would prefer use _elements instead of elements.
And what's the difference using self.elements instead of _elements?

Comment: **So @synthesize is not required in the .m file?** - not anymore. Older Xcode versions required that but starting from Xcode 4.6 (if I remember correctly) Xcode does it for you. **And what's the difference using self.elements instead of _elements** you should read about properties in Objective-C. In short self.elements calls -(void)setElements:(NSMutableArray *)newElements and -(NSMutableArray*)elements methods as getter and setter in cases self.elements=someArray; and someArray=self.elements; respectivly while _elements is plain access to instance variable.

Comment: Okay. I'll read more about properties when I have the time :)

Comment: You are a GOD! Thank you very much! This works. I haven't known, that I can link the datasource and the delegate directly to the viewcontroller. I always add an object and linked it to that because it was explained like that in my programming book. Again Thank you! You are great!

Answer (score 1):

override your _elements getter

```
- (NSMutableArray *)elements
{
    if (!_elements)
        _elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _elements;
}
```

and first time call _elements like

```
self.elements
```

Comment: Overwriting the getter, I get an error:
EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Now I get an empty array instead of nil... This is not much better :D

Comment: this is, you can set and this array always return true value

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this on strong objects

```
whenever you retain the the object you should use self.yourObject

self.elements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", nil];

"elements" should be strong or retain pointer in .h files
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing all of these things.

At the place where you have defined the NSMutableArray property, make sure it is `nonatomic` and `retain`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* elements;
```

In the .m file do:

```
@synthesize elements;
```

Always access it using **self** like this:

```
self.elements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", nil];
```

and preferably whenever you are allocating the array, try to use it like this

```
[self setElements: array2];
```

instead of

```
elements = array2;
```

or

```
self.elements = array2;
```

dangling pointers

Comment: I did all this, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your project and I am wondering this, why are you using 2 instances of elements array? Because in the modern runtime only one instance is needed.

I prefer to declare objects on properties because I think it makes the memory management of the objects loaded from the nib much clearer. Take a look at [memory management of nib objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW4) and I think you will see what I mean.

## Possible solution

Try to reload your pickerView after self.elements is created and has objects in it.

Comment: I also tried without NSMutableArray *elements inside of {}. I only added this, because in much tutorials, I saw this. It's already removed. I just tried it.

Comment: One question, how do you know that array is turning to nil? Also you are setting the object not correctly to NSUserDefaults [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.elements objectAtIndex:[self.elementPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]] forKey:JFSettingsKeyElement];

Comment: I mean is the [self.elementPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] an integer?

Comment: No. It's id (aka long). But I changed it to setInteger:(int)[self.elementPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]
Also if I comment out the content of the loadContent method, elements is still empty.

Comment: Hmm, point me out where do you check out that the NSMutableArray is nil, Make a NSLog after at the last method which gets called or hardcode the [self.elements objectAtIndex:0] and print out the value. Feedback me

Comment: I stepped through the whole project.
At the end of viewDidLoad elements has three objects, but in the next method (numberOfComponentsInPickerView:) it is nil. numberOfComponentsInPickerView is called directly after viewDidLoad.

Comment: I am not familiar with PickerView so is there a method so you can recall the methods of it, again after adding values to the self.elements?

Comment: Maybe reloadAllComponents, but this also changes nothing.
And the PickerView methods are already called after adding the elements.
Okay. Now I'm confused. In the viewDidAppear method, elements is not nil anymore?! That means, I only have to reload the PickerView and it should work... I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Solution is easier for you if you pass the arguments from another viewController to this one, when you present this one, so you don't have to worry about initializing and adding objects to NSMutableArray on this interface. Anyway, I think your delegate methods of pickerView are getting called before you are initializing your self.elements. Anyway asnwer edited.